# How to search a table for a particular keyword that matches a record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these two queries that work just fine. I just want to know, if a user types only a keyword. I still want it to be able to search using the keyword and find a match.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `titles` WHERE `Title` = '$search'";

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `Authors` WHERE `FirstName` = '$search' OR `LastName` = '$search'";
```

Comment: Use the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySql's LIKE keyword:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `titles` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%$search%'";    

 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `Authors` WHERE `FirstName` LIKE '%$search%'
 OR `LastName` LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Full Text Search engine, is available in MyISAM and InnoDB as of 5.6, [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)
It's more powerful than like operator who is limited if you let users to input multiple words, and so on.

Query example:

```
SELECT * FROM authors
WHERE MATCH (FirstName,NastName)
AGAINST ('$query' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM titles WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql LIKE

This is the sytax for Like

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;
```

Eg:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `titles` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Ref http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: You might like to tell him about the wildcard options as well

Comment: What is the %s called? preg_match?

Comment: @Shinji You will get more options ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm